# Can I run calculations on an external ssh server that doesn't have Mathematica installed?

Tags: kernel, remote-access

I am currently running some rather compilex *Mathematica* calculations on my laptop and sometimes run into an out-of-memory errors. However, I have access to some larger simulation servers via ssh, but they don't have *Mathematica* installed on them. Is there a possibility I can use this additional calculation-power for my calculations?

(I already found [ConnectToARemoteKernel](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/howto/ConnectToARemoteKernel.html) but if I understand correctly this only works, if *Mathematica* is installed on both systems.)

Comment: It would depend on your license with Wolfram. My license allows two copies, work and home.  And, while I only have one installed, I can launch two copies in the same computer, but no more than that.

Comment: You are correct in your assumption that you can't run _Mathematica_ computations on a server that doesn't have _Mathematica_ installed.

Comment: ok ... :( i was afraid i would here that. but i thought asking is free :)

Comment: Well, you can write MathLink programs to run on these other machines connected to your *Mathematica* session--but that may not be what you had in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An extended comment.

If I read your question correctly, memory appears to limit your calculations rather than the number of computing kernels.

Following this line of thought, it would help responders to know if your problem comes from processing large data sets, complexity of calculation, calculations that just need lots of memory, or some combination of these.

Some other information would also help, like your computing environment's specifications: CPU, RAM, HD, OS,
Mathematica version.

Some things to try immediately:

Reboot your laptop.
To the degree possible don't open any applications other than Mathematica.
Run your calculations and see if you still get the same errors.

IF you still have the problem, can you identify and isolate the specific code or function that generates the out-of-memory errors?  This would enable people on the site to suggest specific alternatives that may work around the problem (adding various kinds of constraints, options, or specifying a domain for lots of functions can often solve these kinds of issues).

Beyond this, if memory rather than CPU really does limit you, I wonder if you could allocate more virtual memory or even set up remote virtual memory.

Certainly cumbersome, probably impractical, and VERY SLOW, but it might provide you a way to do the calculations without investing in additional Mathematica licenses.

Comment: I did not know what virtual memory meant. After reading [this](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/MemoryManagement.html), I got it, but I still had some questions. The doc page seems to suggest that it is the OS that moves data between virtual memory (hard disk) and RAM and Mathematica just uses that system. I found [this link for mac](http://osxdaily.com/2010/10/08/mac-virtual-memory-swap/) very interesting. Anyway, if you want to have more control over things, I suppose in some cases you could use `DumpSave`.

Answer (score 2):

This is to get an answer on record.

Presuming that you want to evaluate *Mathematica* expressions on a remote server, then it is true that the server will need a *Mathematica* kernel installed.